# R self-deleted all packages and cannot install anymore

Tags: r, rstudio, install.packages

All of a sudden my `R` installation (running on Ubuntu 16.04) output `R execution error` and shut down. After re-opening the session (in `RStudio`) I found out that `R` deleted all present packages on my computer (or better, did not find any of them anymore): I have tried to re-install them all but I always get the `Error in library(<name>) : there is no package called <name>` no matter what package I try to install. For example:

```
> install.packages("data.table")

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/data.table_1.10.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3068135 bytes (2.9 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.9 MB

Error in library(data.table) : there is no package called ‘data.table’
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘data.table’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpl1WV2b/downloaded_packages’
```

and likewise for any other. I have tried changing CRAN mirror manually but it is irrelevant. If I do

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4"
[2] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"                  
[3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                        
[4] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

all the above are empty (they were not before, now they are, it seems everything got wiped off). However

```
ls -l /tmp/Rtmpl1WV2b/downloaded_packages
total 3000
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user 3068135 Jun 23 04:05 data.table_1.10.4.tar.gz
```

so the package is somehow downloaded somewhere despite the error message in R. Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: Unless you specify otherwise, R tries (and does, barring a permissions issue) to install packages to the first path returned by `.libPaths()`. Updating R itself usually (deliberately) changes `.libPaths()` to an empty new directory attached to the version (packages built with old versions can introduce bugs), but the old directories of packages are usually still in your filesystem if you look. Assuming everything didn't get deleted, go search for those files and set `.libPaths` to an appropriate directory. Or just delete everything and start over, if you like.

Comment: Did you just upgrade to R 3.4?

Comment: I did in fact just upgrade R to 3.4.

Comment: @alistaire Even by manually changing the installation location and even by uninstalling and re-installing R from scratch, the *installation of package <whatever> had non-zero exit status* without any other verbal explanation still occurs. Is this a general problem of the new R version?